# connecting mongodb database to a webapplication in Netbeans environment

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans-7.4, database

I am completely new to programing .Can you help with creating a mongdb database and connect it to a java based web application. I am using Netbeans 7.4 ide.

Comment: Please check out some tutorials online, once you write the code and have issues with it, post it here. Please know that its not the right forum for these kind of question.

Comment: May be you could begin with : _installation_ = [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/), _getting started_ = [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/) and then the Java part = [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/)